# Superlative of a future action

Tags: future, superlative-degree

I am writing a scientific document and I need to talk about a device that has not yet been built, but when it is, it will be the most powerful of its kind. So, how do I refer to it?

My current sentence:

> This is the device, the most powerful telescope ever built.

Since it has not been built, is this sentence correct?

I was thinking:

> This is the device, the most powerful telescope ever to be built.

Comment: Please give more context to the statement. In its current form, it represents a question without a question mark an the end. Writing the full sentence will help us to give a detailed answer.

Comment: Well.. that is as complete as it is. Imagine I am showing you the design of a telescope and say "This is the device, the most powerful telescope ever built". But I wonder if it is a mistake, because it has not been actually built yet, but whenever its construction is finished, it will be the most powerful. So I want to know if I should change the sentence because of this.

Comment: Upvote the answer if it works. If it doesn't, point out why in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I loved the second suggestion. Pretty fancy ;)

Comment: Pleasure to be of help. :)

Comment: To some extent, the most appropriate word choice depends on your level of confidence that the device will in fact be built. If you have high confidence, Rio1210's suggestions are on the money; if you have low or middling confidence, you might want to replace the _when_ with _if_ in each of the two suggested wordings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in writing  *"This is the device, the most powerful telescope ever to be built."* is that it implies that no telescope more powerful than it will be built in the future, which I presume is not your intended meaning.

Instead, you could simply write:

*"This device will be the most powerful telescope when built"*

or

*"When built, this device will be the most powerful telescope of its kind."*

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, though a little unwieldy, to say
 *This device, to be the most powerful ever built*; you could insert *intended* or some similar verb before 'to'.

Comment: I like it. I didn't think of changing the place of the verb, thank you!